# Find distance between a set and a point.

Tags: real-analysis

Find the distance of the set $\{   (x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n: \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n =1, x_n\ge0 \} $ from point $0$ using $\mathcal{l^2}$ norm.

How can I estimate $\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n^2}$ knowing the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n =1$ and all the numbers being non-negative?

Comment: Sorry, edited the question.

Comment: You mean $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call
$$a_n (k)= \begin{cases} 1/n & k=1, \dots n \\ 0 & k >n\end{cases}$$
You can easily check that $\sum_k a_n(k)=1$, so $a_n$ belongs to your set.

Now
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} ||a_n -0||_2=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (a_n(k)-0)^2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{1/n} = 0$$
hence your distance is $0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust We found that $0$ belongs to the closure of the set: this means that the distance is $0$. If we call $X= \{ (x_n) : \sum x_n = 1 , x_n \ge 0\} \subseteq \ell^2$, we want to compute $d_{\ell^2} (0,X)$

Comment: Ok, my bad, the distance is to the set of sequences, not to a particular sequence. [Fake edit to upvote.]